# Error 462 VBA - Automation between Excel & PPT

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to automate copying of certain exhibits from Excel to a PPT template for ~500 different situations. Unfortunately, I am running into errors where it throws error 462 inconsistently. I've looked through online sources for a few hours and couldnt find anything that helped. I understand a common error is late binding; however, I've tried to apply this as best as I could. Your help is very much appreciated..

```
Dim myBook As Workbook
Set myBook = ThisWorkbook

Dim pptName As String
Dim DestinationPPT As String
Dim myShape As Object
Dim ppt As Object
Dim mySlide As Object

Dim pptA As Object
Set pptA = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")


DestinationPPT = myBook.path & "\template.pptx"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Call Module1.mkdirectories(myBook.path)

Dim inputRange As Excel.Range
Dim c As Excel.Range
Dim worksheetCt As Integer
worksheetCt = 8
myBook.Worksheets("input").Activate

Set inputRange = Evaluate(myBook.Worksheets("input").Range("c4").Validation.Formula1)
For Each c In inputRange
    Range("c4").Value = c
    Calculate

    Set ppt = pptA.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)

    For worksheetCt = 8 To 39
        'On Error Resume Next
        myBook.Activate
        myBook.Worksheets(worksheetCt).Range("Print_Area").Copy
        DoEvents

        pptA.Activate
        'ppt.Activate

        Set mySlide = ppt.Slides(worksheetCt - 5)

        'Call Module1.UglyWait
        **mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2**
        'Call Module1.UglyWait

        **Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)**
```

bolded lines are where the code fails..

Comment: While [Runtime error 462 Excel VBA using Word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29687724/62576) mentions Word and not Powerpoint, I'd wager that the solution is the same for your problem.

Comment: hey Ken - thanks for responding. i think since I set up each object with being a reference to the PowerPoint Application and PowerPoint deck, this isnt the right solution. do you have any other thoughts? I attempted to add the reference to the application back in and didnt have any luck.

Comment: It's telling you that you need to reference the Powerpoint application in those calls. Your code is executing in Excel, which does not have a presentation or slides. Don't *think* that you've done things right - if you had, you wouldn't have the problem. :-)

Comment: I guess I should rephrase my point, I set the powerpoint deck and slide as objects but used the PowerPoint Application with regards to both of them. For example, I said ppt = pptA.Presentations.Open ... and then myslide = ppt.slides ...

in both cases, the call to the PowerPoint application is there... am I misunderstanding this? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I tried that, and it threw an error. Any other suggestions @chrisneilsen

Answer (score 0):

I have found that by doing all of my copying and pasting of charts in a separate procedure I've stopped having the problem.  I guess passing the slide to another procedure magically results in it being valid, and putting the copy/paste in a loop where it tries multiple times seems to have solved the pasting problem.

```
Public Sub PPPasteShape(mySlide As PowerPoint.Slide, pc As ChartObject)
Dim i As Integer
Dim worked As Boolean
i = 0
pc.Copy
worked = False
  
  Do While (i < 5 And worked = False)
    Debug.Print "Try: " & CStr(i)
    If i > 0 Then
      Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    End If
    worked = PPTryPasteShape(mySlide)
    i = i + 1
  Loop
End Sub

Public Function PPTryPasteShape(mySlide As PowerPoint.Slide) As Boolean

On Error GoTo err

mySlide.Shapes.Paste
PPTryPasteShape = True
Exit Function

err:
PPTryPasteShape = False
End Function

Public Sub PPPasteRange(mySlide As PowerPoint.Slide, rng As Range)
Dim i As Integer
Dim worked As Boolean
i = 0
rng.Copy
  
  Do While (i < 5 And worked = False)
    Debug.Print "Try: " & CStr(i)
    If i > 0 Then
      Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    End If
    worked = PPTryPasteRange(mySlide)
    i = i + 1
  Loop
End Sub


Public Function PPTryPasteRange(mySlide As PowerPoint.Slide) As Boolean

On Error GoTo err

mySlide.Shapes.Paste
PPTryPasteRange = True
Exit Function

err:
PPTryPasteRange = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe declare it as

```
Dim myShape As Powerpoint.Shape
Dim ppt As Powerpoint.Presentation
Dim mySlide As Powerpoint.Slide
```